# How to render many ExtJS trees using a single data store

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, tree, extjs4

First of all, I am novice in ExtJS
I am working on Ext 4 Tree since few days.

The requirement is such that I want to display 3-4 representation of same tree at the same time. I want to do this using single data store.

Tree 1 will show all nodes without checkboxes
Tree 2 will show all nodes with checkboxes
Tree 3 will show only parent nodes (folders) and no leaf nodes (files)

I tried to do these using same data store but expanding/collapsing of one tree results into inconsistently expanding/collapsing of other. Also for checkbox, I have to denibe "checkbox: true/false" in data store which I have no idea how to control in Ext.

Please help me. It will be much help if there already an example around.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is - you have just one copy of the store and all your trees are subscribed to this store events, so when something is fired by the store all trees react to that. And btw, same applies if you want for example to show couple different grids using same store.

If you need to have different behavior for each control you need to either constantly subscribe/unsubscribe from store events in each tree (depend on which one is focused right now) or more simple solution - to clone store and have individual copy for each tree.

Comment: It will be helpful if you please let me know how to subscribe/unsubscribe to store. I think it may do a trick. I searched the docs but could not find anything relevant to that.

Comment: Check the source code for tree/grid components - bindStore method. That's where all happening.